# Oracle - Insert one row per hour between two times

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Given two times, how do i insert one row per hour in the Oracle table?

```
Start Time: 3.00 PM

End Time: 6.00 PM

Name: 'Asdfg'
```

Expected Data to be generated:

```
Name      StartTime       EndTime
ASDFG       3.00           4.00
ASDFG       4.00,          5.00
ASDFG       5.00           6.00
```

Comment: Where are you inserting it **from**? A client application or a stored procedure (as "plsql" tag might suggest)?

Comment: inside the SP. I am getting two parameters as StartTime and EndTime.

Comment: Also, do you want actual INSERT **executions** to be spaced by an hour, or you only need "space out" the data being inserted, while the INSERT itself can be done in one go?

Comment: You might want to look at the following link: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Scheduler10g.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it without PL/SQL, in one insert. You could parameterize the start and end times and use it in your procedure:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (NAME, starttime, endtime)
(SELECT 'ASDFG', t1, t2
   FROM (SELECT to_char((to_date('3.00 PM','HH.MI AM')+(LEVEL-1)/24),'HH.MI AM') t1
              , to_char((to_date('3.00 PM','HH.MI AM')+LEVEL/24), 'HH.MI AM') t2
           FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (to_date('6.00 PM','HH.MI AM') - to_date('3.00 PM','HH.MI AM')) * 24));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CurrentTime := StartTime;
WHILE CurrentTime <= EndTime
LOOP
     INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (CurrentTime);

     CurrentTime  := CurrentTime + (1 / 24);

END LOOP;

COMMIT;
```

Should do the trick (I did not try it...)